# Error in reading JSON to a variable in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read a json file to a javascript variable. I have read the same file previously. So the json file is in correct format.

```
var net_json = {};
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/karate.json",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function() {
        alert("Error loading the file");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        net_json = data;
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

But it always returns alert Error loading the file. Both json and js files are in the same location.

Comment: What is the location of `karate.json` w.r.t. the document/page where the above JS code is executed?

Comment: What does it say in the network panel? Do you realize that the path is not based off the location of the Js file but the page it is on?

Comment: `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);}` catch the error with this and see what you get as `responseText`!

Comment: If the json file is in the same location, you shouldn't need the slash.

Comment: @JohnnyFun - the location of the js file doesn't matter. What matters is if the page the above code is run and the json file are in the same location.

Comment: Oh, right. But yeah, keep the network tab open. It will tell you all.

Comment: @JohnnyFun - did you pasted the total ajax function here, if yes check with `success` function it is not closed.

Comment: Oh, this isn't my question, man. He's just gotta hit f12, and all his questions will be answered. I had just made a useless comment above, haha. I'll just leave now...

Comment: It is not f12 in all operating systems. ;)

Comment: Haha, get outta here. Damn kids and their computas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your structure is like this

- index.html
- js/myJS.js
- js/karate.json

which means the url should be

```
url:"js/karate.json",
```

The relative path is based on the page, not where the JavaScript file resides.